# Getting "Invalid server address" error while trying to fetch from Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: python, scripting, active-directory

I want to fetch user details from Active Directory of Windows Server 2012 r2 from Python Scripting... This code is showing Invalid server address. Any ideas?

```py
import sys

from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES, 
AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, SUBTREE

from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPCursorError

server_name = 'MyServerName' 

domain_name = 'MyDomainName' 

user_name = 'MyName'

password = 'MyPassword'


format_string = '{:25} {:>6} {:19} {:19} {}'
print(format_string.format('Users', 'Logins', 'Last Login', 'Expires', 'Description'))

server = Server(server_name, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user='{}\\{}'.format(domain_name, user_name), password=password, authentication=NTLM,auto_bind=True)
print(conn.result)

conn.search('dc={},dc=com'.format(domain_name), '(objectclass=User)',attributes=[ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES])

for e in conn.entries:
    try:
        desc = e.description
    except LDAPCursorError:
        desc = ""



print(format_string.format(str(e.name), str(e.logonCount), str(e.lastLogon)[:19], str(e.accountExpires)[:19], desc))
```